# Rake cp permission denied on windows

Tags: ruby, rake, file-permissions, rakefile

Here's the rake file.

```
task :default  => :release

task :release do
    target = 'releases/' + Time.new.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    mkdir_p target
    cp Dir["web"], target 
end
```

I get "permission denied - web".
what do I have to do to give rake the same rights I have when it runs, in windows.

Comment: also tried the cp without the dir part, just as 2 paths, still no dice.

Comment: Same issue here, using Ruby 1.9.3p0 with Rake 0.9.2.2 (i386-mingw32). Both mv and cp have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, as simple as the target was readonly. In this case `web` might not exist, or might not be readable.

I'm no expert in rake, but where is `Dir` declared?

Comment: `Dir` is Ruby Standrd Library.

Answer (score 0):

What about using sh?

```
sh %& copy "#{Dir['web']}" "#{target}" &
```